# SQL Server 2008 Express does not start manually on my local system

Tags: sql-server-2008

The request failed or the service did not respond in a timely fashion. consult the event log or other applicable error logs for details.

I have tried these solution but it didn't work for me.

1. Disable VIA
2. Change the Reporting Service account
3. I also tried with different settings for following:

   Go to `Start > Run > and type regedit`
   Navigate to: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control`
   With the control folder selected, right click in the pane on the right and select new `DWORD` value
   Name the new `DWORD`: `ServicesPipeTimeout`
   Right-click `ServicesPipeTimeout`, and then click `Modify`
   Click `Decimal`, type `180000`, and then click OK
   Restart the computer

Comment: Rather that trying random voodoo (VIA? really?) why don't you do exactly what the message tell you to do: **consult the event log or other applicable error logs for details.**

Comment: my message is coming this The Request Failed or the service didnot respond in a timely fashion. Consult the eventlog or other applicable error logs for details.